# 5.1 Sound channels doesn't work correct

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa

I've got Xonar DGX sound card and Ubuntu 16.04 OS.
Also I am using Front R+L, Center + Woofer speakers. If I choose 4.0 profile, my speakers work perfect, but woofer is not. If I choose 5.1 profile, I can hear sound only from FR + woofer and FL is recognized as RL.
Could someone help me to setup speakers? I'm new to linux and don't want to move back to Windows.
(I tried to use alsamixer, didn't help).
Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing pulseaudio-equalizer. It helped with issues with my Xonar DS (very low volume sound, and only stereo mode worked, no 5.1).

To do so, do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

If you get stuttering audio while using equalizer, edit /etc/pulse/default.pa as root with a text editor and add "tsched=0" to the "load-module module-udev-detect" and "load-module module-detect" lines - this is how it should look:

```
### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev/hal support)
load-module module-detect tsched=0
.endif
```

Source: [SYSTEM-WIDE PULSEAUDIO EQUALIZER UPDATED FOR UBUNTU 16.10, 16.04 AND 14.04, LINUX MINT 18 AND 17](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/system-wide-pulseaudio-equalizer.html)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.